# meaning of 104 error on Locust

Tags: iis, performance-testing, locust

I am a confused that I got the following error which means client and/or server closes the connection. I am using Locust and server responding stable and time is not much, but sometime I got this error from IIS.

With the error, my number of users is decreased one or keeping stable? How can I check the connected user? What kind of problem will this error cause?

```
ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer')),)
```